# Is it possible to use five.grok to register portlets in Plone 4.1?

Tags: portlet, plone, grok

I looked into five.grok and found no reference to Portlets. Can it be done?

Comment: I don't think this question is going to be very well received without more detail…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

five.grok does not have support for portlets. If you want it, you would need to implement a grokker in an add-on package. See plone.directives.form for some examples of custom grokkers.